# dispatching commands sequentially on file save? Coffee init

Tags: atom-editor, platformio

**The code :**

```
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  editor.onDidSave ->
    view = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor())
    atom.commands.dispatch(view, 'platformio-ide-terminal:insert-custom-text-1')
    .then () -> atom.commands.dispatch(view, 'platformio-ide-terminal:insert-custom-text-2')
```

Why doesn't atom allow me to sequentially execute commands from different packages in my init file like this?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why it isn't working with that little information provided

- does dispatching any of those commands work (e.g. in the console)?
- is it the chaining that isn't working?
- are there any errors in the console?
- did you restart Atom after updating the init file?

I've refactored your code to use ES6, since I prefer async/await over "thenable" syntax. In order to use it, rename `init.coffee` to `init.js`:

```js
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors(editor => {
  return editor.onDidSave(async () => {
    const view = atom.views.getView(atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor());

    await atom.commands.dispatch(view, 'platformio-ide-terminal:insert-custom-text-1');
    await atom.commands.dispatch(view, 'platformio-ide-terminal:insert-custom-text-2');
  });
});
```

Take note that I tested the snippet using commands of which I'm sure that they are available. However, I set them back to those from your example (again: make sure they work!)